# Object property becoming null after first use

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some code in my controller which looks like:

```
var db = new ComicEntities();
            var user = db.Users.Where(i => i.UserName == username).Include(i => i.UserFavorites);
            var AuthorComics = db.ComicAuthors.Where(i => i.User_Id == 1)
                         .Include(i => i.Comic)
                         .Include("Comic.Chapters")
                         .Include("Comic.Chapters.Pages");
            var Comics = AuthorComics.Select(i => i.Comic).Include("Chapters").Include("Chapters.Pages");
            return View(new LocalUserViewModel { User = user.First(), Comics = Comics.ToList() });
```

My view looks like this:

```
@model Comics.Models.LocalUserViewModel

@foreach(var favorite in @Model.User.UserFavorites)
            {
                <div class="chapter-info">
                    <span class="chapter-info-title misc-comic-title">@favorite.Comic.Title</span>
                    <span class="chapter-info-page misc-comic-info">@favorite.DateFavorited</span>
                </div>
            }
```

The problem is that after the first iteration of the `foreach` loop, the property `@favorite.Comic` becomes null.

Comment: Didn't you try to use For loop instead Foreach? Sietimes it helps.

Comment: I have tried that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your Controller looks up the User and fetches the favorites eagerly, but doesn't fetch the next level down.  You need to modify your query slightly, i.e.

```
var user = db.Users.Where(i => i.UserName == username)
                            .Include(i => i.UserFavorites)
                            .Include("UserFavorites.Comic");
```

note that other queries do fetch the information, but they are on a different object graph....